# How to properly handle Long Lived Tokens on Facebook Auth

Tags: reactjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, next.js

I am looking to figure out what is the proper way to handle long lived facebook auth tokens and what is the best way to check for expirations.

It is my understanding that you start with a short lived token and exchange for a long lived one. Then you get the response for "expires_in" and then we can check against that.

My question is in the scenario of having many users with my application, would you use a cron job to check against each users "expires_in" and then from there trigger whose needs to be refreshed and communicate that to the user?

I wonder from a cron job perspective this could be a job that takes a very long time to complete so do companies have a better way to do this? Do you have many cron jobs that are only responsible for x number of users and then more get created as the app grows?

Comment: What about this do you expect to take such a long time to complete? The _“check against each users `expires_in`”_ part should not require more than _one_ query against the user database.

Comment: _“would you use a cron job”_ - depends, on what you are actually using the tokens for, resp. what type of functionality your app offers to begin with.